# Moodle - How to Make SQL Join Table

Tags: php, moodle

[image]

I want to separate "Student" by group, example:
Student A, B, and C are in Group A,
Student D, E, and F are in Group B.
Then, how to show it in "Student"

I hope anyone can help me. Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain what information you want to display?

Comment: in the "Student" menu, I want to show the separated group, like group A has student A, student B, and C. Group B has student e, f, g.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a custom profile field for the users called 'group' - use a menu of choices with A and B.

Site administration -> Users -> Accounts -> User profile fields

http://docs.moodle.org/26/en/User_profile_fields

Then edit each of your users profiles so that they are part of Group A or Group B. Or you could do this with an insert query into mdl_user_info_data.

Then modify this SQL for your query

```
SELECT u.username, d.data AS groupname
FROM mdl_user u
JOIN mdl_user_info_data d ON d.userid = u.id
JOIN mdl_user_info_field f ON f.shortname = 'group'
```